# Cordova is running the wrong Java version. How do I get Cordova to run a specific Java version?

Tags: java, android, cordova

```
[javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
```

and

```
error: strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
    [javac]    switch (xmlData[i][1]) {
    [javac]           ^
    [javac]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
```

I am getting warnings and errors that I am running Java 1.5 when compiling an APK with Cordova for Android. I can't use strings in switch statements. (the compilation process errors)

My system is 64-bit Windows 7. My Cordova version is 3.5. I am using git-scm. (http://git-scm.com/)

- I am running this command: `cordova run android --release`.
- My Java environment variable lists `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20` as the Java directory.
- My path enviroment variable sets the Java path as the first item in the list.
- Every Java patch and version is uninstalled except what I just re-installed from Oracle's site.
- I restarted my computer.
- `java -version` gives me `java version "1.8.0_20"`.
- `javac -version` gives me `javac 1.8.0_20`.
- All my targets are `=android-19`, `=debug`, or `=release`.
- `android:minSdkVersion` is always set to "14", everywhere.
- `android:targetSdkVersion` is always set to "19", everywhere.

How can I force Cordova to run Java 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix for command line builds, add these lines (or set appropriate values if already present) to your ant `build.xml` property file (for example if using Android SDK, it's in `${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml`):

```xml
<property name="java.target" value="1.7" />
<property name="java.source" value="1.7" />
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that your Plugin's project base must use Ant, not Maven. Otherwise, this answer will be ignored at compile time!

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on your project(Package Explorer) and select "**Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties**"
2. Right-click on your project and select "**Properties -> Java Compiler**", check "**Enable project specific settings**" and select **1.7 or 1.8** from "**Compiler compliance settings**" select box.
3. then Rebuild your project (**Project -> Clean**)

Comment: Can you quickly just try to set JDK 1.7 instead of 1.8 ? and give it a try ?

Comment: Well, things compile. So, yes, I have the ant path set correctly. I'll try JDK 1.7 tomorrow and see if it helps.

Comment: Ok. I ran JDK 1.7 and it doesn't give the 1.5 warning or error. Then I installed 1.8 and it's happening again. Any idea why that is though? It'd be nice to use both the latest JDK AND have Cordova compile to the right version...

Comment: It means there is something which is only compatible with JDK 1.7. Try to check the installed versions compatibility with JDK 1.8; check ant or node or git & cordova versions that you have.

Comment: Well, node and git were very recently updated. Cordova is 3.5. I am using git-scm (2014-09-30), but I can't find any problems with it via Google. Ant might be the problem (``Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010``) but I seem to recall this text is a lie.

Answer (score 1):

I created 2 plugins because i had this same issue.
The credits for the idea go to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31032409/5392438).

- [cordova-plugin-java6](https://github.com/cvuser0/cordova-plugin-java6) tries to enfore Java 6.
- [cordova-plugin-java7](https://github.com/cvuser0/cordova-plugin-java7) tries to enfore Java 7.

You cannot fetch these plugins from the npm repository, so use the command listed in the README.md

It works for me, if it doesn't for you, please use the issues and pull request functions on the github repository.

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate answers](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Instead, tailor each of your answers to the specific question. If you have the necessary reputation points, you can [flag](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) or [vote-to-close](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) questions as duplicates, where appropriate.