# error: diamond operator is not supported in -source1.5

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova, maven

I am creating an app which uses cordova ionic and angular and for barcode scanning i am using native and able to integrate with the javascript code.If I run the project using eclipse IDE its working fine but if I do ionic run android - getting the above error - diamond operator is not supported in - source 1.5

For native i used this link https://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/ and its working fine.

Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: You are using `<>` which is not supported by the java source you are using since it got added only in Java 1.7

Comment: parametrize the diamond `<>` with class elements that must contain

Comment: $ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: @CeilingGecko if i run using ide its running without any errors.:(

Comment: @sudarshan it might be the case that the IDE compiles it against a different java source than the android

Answer (score 11):

Try to add apache plugnin to your Pom.xml under Build tag as @Sudarshan mentioned.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

This would resolve issue

Answer (score 5):

You are using `<>` which is not supported by the java source you are using since it got added only in Java 1.7

Find the places in your source code where you are using `<>` and properly specify the generic that is implied.

e.g. if it was:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

rewrite it as

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Note:** Although diamond operator is a handy shortcut, I'd recommend to always specify full generics as it not only adds to readability, it also does not create a 1.7+ dependency on your source. (Which as we can see can sometimes lead to problems.)

Comment: is there any way to update the java version for the project..because in some many places it has to be changed

Comment: @sudarshan If you are using Cordova you can check the answers in [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308156/cordova-is-running-the-wrong-java-version-how-do-i-get-cordova-to-run-a-specifi)

Comment: @sudarshan Yes, if you want Maven to use something else you have to [configure it](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

Comment: <properties>
        <sourceJdk>1.7</sourceJdk>
        <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
 </properties>
 
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
  
  <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.1</version>
     <configuration>
         <source>1.7</source>
         <target>1.7</target>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
i pasted these lines in pom.xml but in vain

Comment: @CeilingGecko after changing the java target version in tools directory in ant folder ..now i am getting cannot find symbol error ...once i give ionic run android

Comment: @sudarshan can you add a detailed description (e.g. stack trace) of the new error in your original post?

Answer (score 0):

**Right click on project -> Properties -> Project Facets -> tick Java, select 1.7

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @Swarit Agarwal answer, below is the full content of the pom.xml for easy reference.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>order-rest-marvin</groupId>
  <artifactId>order-rest-marvin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <!-- to resolve the issue about maven plugin not supported (older versions) -->
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

[image]