# How to change java version used by cordova subprojects

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have a Cordova project, and I am building a android plugin for it. My plugin then uses a library that uses the diamond operation (<>). I tried to run it but I receive this error :

```
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
    ArrayList<Node> selectedProviders = new ArrayList<>();
                                                      ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

When I run:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_67
```

I research before posting and some people resolved by changing the ant `config.xml` to

```
<property name="java.target" value="1.7" />
<property name="java.source" value="1.7" />
```

But it didnt worked for me.

I also tried make a `build-extra-gradle` file to set-up the `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility`, but it just appears to resolve the main project, not the subproject that I use on my plugin.

Comment: So an external library that you use, uses the diamond operator? And the project where you use it in, how exactly do you build it? Ant or gradle?

Comment: Yeah, a external library use the diamond operator. I import my library using       `<framework src="src/android/filepicker-android/filepicker-library" custom="true" type="projectReference"/>` inside the plugin.xml file. I am not sure how to do it with gradle nor if this is the right way to do it. This library it's on gradle, though. Can you please tell me where to put the `compile 'io.filepicker:filepicker-android:3.8.13’` so I could import it by gradle?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio? If so, open Module Settings on your project, then go to SDK Location and see what's under JDK Location. Make sure it's pointing to the correct JDK folder (jdk.1.7.XXX).

Comment: Actually I am using the command line interface (CLI) for cordova.

Comment: give output of javac -version also

Comment: just add it, @AtillaOzgur

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, what worked for me was adding all the sub-projects(libraries) that you plugin uses as main-libraries of yout cordova project.

Here what I did:
Copy all the libraries to libs, go to eclipse>build path>order and export>Mark everything. 
After that, you have to create a build-extras.gradle file on your root/platforms/android folder. Put this code on your file:

```
ext.postBuildExtras = {
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    allprojects {
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }
}
}
```

Keeping referencing in the subprojects, though. You have to make the reference from the project and the subproject (not sure why, but worked.).