# IONIC: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this error when I try to compile a release application in ionic

```
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
```

ionic info:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.1.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 2.0.1-201702132005
```

System:

```
Node : v6.12.2
npm  : 5.8.0
OS   : Windows 10
```

Comment: Did you got any answer?

Comment: did you get the answer @ShreenilPatel

Comment: No, still suffering with this issue. @MSD

Comment: removing and adding the platform seems to be working @ShreenilPatel ... if you can do that ... try it ...

Comment: I've tried it for lot of times. What is your jdk version and ionic android platform version? @MSD

Comment: android is 6.2.3 and jdk is 1.6 in build.gradle file@ShreenilPatel

Comment: I had the same problem, solved it by migrating the cordova-android plugin to 6.4.0

Comment: Also it seems you have to force the platform to use Java 8. I followed this answer for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31032409/1843141